# Movement tracking in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, perl, database-design

I am fairly new to website and database design, my only experience previously being some very basic MS Access databases and basic courses on Codeacademy. I have decided to try my hand at making a web based game to cut my teeth on programming. I was hoping someone could give me some insight on database design, specifically ad-hoc scheduling of future events.

The current plan is to have a simple space adventure game; the stars are laid out on a 2 dimension Cartesian plane (so, each star has an (X,Y) coordinate). So, I have 2 basic tables showing:

SHIP:

- Player (Varchar)
- Ship (Varchar)
- CurrentXCoOrd (int)
- CurrentYCoOrd(int)

MAP

- STARID (Int)
- SystemName (varchar)
- XCoOrd (int)
- YCoOrd (Int)

Lets assume that my player has a ship at a system located at the coordinates (1,1) and wishes to make a journey to a system at coordinates (2,2). If this journey were to take, say 10 minutes, what would be the best way to set up the database to record the ships arrival in the new star system? (the ship wouldn't need to journey from one coordinate to the other, simply disappearing from the origin and appearing at the destination is enough.)

I was considering updating the database to show the ship was in motion, and then updating the database again 10 minutes later to show the ships arrival, but to be honest I'm not sure how I would set up that scheduling. With that in mind, I am now considering that instead of recording when the ship launches and when it arrives, I should instead just record arrivals with a timestamp showing when the ship landed and just calculate from that if the ship is in motion or not.

So, I would drop the X and Y CoOrdinate fields from the SHIP table and instead have a table called POSITION

POSITION:

- Player (Varchar)
- ArrivalTime (DateTime)
- XCoOrd (int)
- YCoOrd (int)

The website would then check to see if the arrival timestamp has passed in order to work out if the ship is in motion.

That way, if the player closes his browser and reopens later, nothing is interrupted and now I only update the database once (showing arrival) rather than twice (showing launch and arrival). Could anyone confirm if this is a viable means of tracking the player movements? I am doing this to learn, so am perfectly willing to attempt any suggestions offered. :)

The database is MySQL and the website will be in Perl.

This is my first post here, so please accept my apologies if I have not been clear enough in my question. I searched the archives but did not find anything that matched what I was looking for.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally seems a sensible approach. Two suggestions though.

1. Consider using a "stardate" time (int?) and translating to/from real time. That way if you need to have a pause in the game because the server is offline then you can.
2. Decide whether you want to record actions (a journeys table) or results (a positions table) or both.

From an audit/rewind+replay point of view a set of action tables (journeys, landing, attacks, repairs) might make sense. However, for the "current state of play" you probably don't want to  re-run every action since the start of the game. Although redundant, regular "results" tables (positions, ship_damages, ship_stores) with timestamps let you track "current" state or key points in the past. The tables could be regenerated from a starting state and all subsequent actions and can be treated as a cache. No direct updating - let triggers do it for you as you add new actions to the database.

Finally, consider [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) for your database needs - it's big and it can take a while to get to grips with it, but it's one of the better object-based db wrappers regardless of language.

Answer (score 0):

Capture DepartureTime AND ArrivalTime. Set them both when the ship departs: `DepartureTime = NOW(), ArrivalTime = NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`. Ship is in motion when `NOW() BETWEEN DepartureTime AND ArrivalTime`.